# FactoryGirl build strategy with nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is it possible to preserve the build strategy when I have a factory for a model that has an association to a second model, which itself has an association to a third model?

In the example below, a Post is associated with a User, and a User is associated with a City.  Even when `:strategy => :build` is used for all associations, `post.user` and `post.user.city` end up getting saved to the database.  In the interests of a speedy test suite, can I prevent these database writes from happening?

```
Factory.define do 
  factory :user do
    name "A User"
    association :city, :strategy => :build
  end

  factory :city do
    name "A City"
  end

  factory :post do
    title "A Post"
    body  "Some text here"
    association :user, :strategy => :build
  end
end

post = FactoryGirl.build(:post)

post.new_record?           # True
post.user.new_record?      # False
post.user.city.new_record? # False
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the alternative block syntax?

```
Factory.define do 
  factory :user do
    name "A User"
    city { |city| city.association :city, :strategy => :build }
  end

  factory :city do
    name "A City"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like FactoryBot (formerly `FactoryGirl`) added `use_parent_strategy` as a configuration option in v4.8.0. It is turned off by default, to turn it on add the following to your `spec/rails_helper`:

```
FactoryGirl.use_parent_strategy = true
```

Relevant pull request on the `factory_bot` repo: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/pull/961

Answer (score 0):

As @messanjah said, however for older versions (< v4.8.0) you can do the following:

```
association :user, :strategy => @build_strategy.class
```